# Funding opportunities for small project collaboration between EU and US?

Tags: united-states, funding, europe

I'm a early career researcher in Italy (University of Bolzano) and I have a colleague who is Senior Research Scientist at the National Institute for Aerospace (private contractor of NASA at the Langley Research Center).

We are collaborating and we would like to find funding to do it. Is there any channel for funding "small" bilateral projects between EU and US institutions like ours?

From the US side, from what I understood, it is very difficult to fund anything outside the US. From the EU side it might be easier to fund a project with a US partner, but EU-funded projects are usually large and demanding.

Any hint?